# Java client/server communication, what I need to learn

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming, client-server

I'm new to Java Networking (not Java), I trying to develop a client application that connect to a server, so the server can receive database table and store them online, activate the application: when the user enter activation information, the application connect to the server, send those information, and then the server reply. what I need to know is what technologies/classes can acheive this?? **what I need to learn**?? is it Java RMI or {InetAdress, URL/URI, URLConnection, Socket, ServerSocket, UDP..} Stuff or what exaclty ??

I'm currently reading **Java Network Programming**, Elliotte Rusty Harold, is this what I need to learn??

I developed a JavaFX 8 application and it's out there, it's free, now I'm trying to develop a payed version, and one of the thing I will add is client/server communication. Thanks a lot

Comment: There are better books. Check out its reviews at Amazon. Modesty forbids I should name another.

Answer (score 3):

> what I need to know is what technologies/classes can achieve this??
>   what I need to learn?? is it Java RMI or {InetAdress, URL/URI,
>   URLConnection, Socket, ServerSocket, UDP..} Stuff or what exactly ??

As per the given requirement, it'd be enough for you to learn coding with Java Socket Programming. You don't need a URL/URI unless you're going to connect it to the internet.

And, you should start with sockets/server-sockets, then TCP/UDP is easy to decide based upon the requirement of the application. If the data is critical, you should go for TCP, which is slower as compared to UDP, which in fact doesn't guarantee the packets will arrive in order, or, even if they'd arrive or not. So, you could go with DatagramSocket/Packet OR normal Socket based on whether you use UDP/TCP.

Talking about Java RMI, that is a way too old technology. But, it is good to know this technology. That technology could be used to implement distributed application programming, so obviously you can achieve even the Client-Server communication with that. But, that's somewhat imprecise to use RMI for such an easy task.

My personal suggestion --- Learn some basic networking with the book mentioned below by the author Esmond Pitt, who is among us even here as a fellow member of this community.

> I'm currently reading Java Network Programming, Elliotte Rusty Harold,
>   is this what I need to learn??

I also started learning Java Network programming with the same book,but, the author has made the book too complex for a beginner.It is OK to continue if you want to make a career in Java Network Programming. If not, then you should start with some easier text book like [Fundamental Networking in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1846280303), though this book is somewhat outdated and still revolves around JDK 1.5 as no new publishing has been done for this book after 2006. That is an easier to read book, and even the author of the book([EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp)) is active here on Stack Overflow. You shouldn't get dumbstrucked if he answers your questions here. BTW, I got to know about his books very recently and I enjoyed having a review of that book.

Comment: "You don't need a URL/URI unless you're going to connect it to the internet." yes the server is in the internet (will be on amazon aws), thanks a lot for your in depth reply man

Comment: @usertest-You're most welcome. BTW, don't get astonished by the presence of the author of that book here. Maybe, he may write an answer for this question. His book is good enough to get introductory idea about networking in java; and then you can easily turn to Internet(StackOverflow) for any doubt, or even in confusion. Thanks EJP, by the way. See EJP here ---> http://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp

Comment: @usertest - If this answer helped, please accept this answer. See how to accept an answer ---> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work